# Vue.js / Laravel: How to apply css file dynamically

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I want users to be able to use a dark theme on my website. So when they click the according button, a .css file should be applied on my website. How would I approach this with Vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

Vue has the option to change styles dynamically. You can toggle between classes. Just have a main div where you'd toggle between light and dark theme and beneath it keep the same name for the styles in both the css files.

See if this helps (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)